# how to set expiration to the generated password within 24 hours in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passwords, email-validation

here is the complete detail ...
i need to set expiration to the forget password option generated  password which is sent to the user by email within 24 hours since after that time the user should have to request for a new password in node.js and how to set check on that generated password that it is used within its validity .
i am using this code for forgot password

```
exports.sendForgotPasswordEmail = function(user, password) {
  var emailText = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), process.app.i18n('forgot-password.html')), 'UTF-8');
  var body = util.format(
    emailText,
    user.name,
    process.app.conf.get(process.app.conf.HomePage),
    user.email,
    password,
    process.app.conf.get(process.app.conf.SupportEmail)
  );
  var subject = process.app.i18n('Recover Password !!');

  async.nextTick(function() {
    notifications.util.mail.sendEmail(user.email, null, null, subject, body, null);
  });

  return;
};
'
```

please help me out of this...!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer to your question will be the same regardless of the used technology. I assume that you have to have some kind of database with user accounts. In this database you have to remember when a user requested a new password (a reset of a password).

The next time a particular user will try to log in you only need to compare the current date with the date of the last request for a new password in the database (if is exists / is not null).  If is not within allowed limit (in this case 24 hours) you should report an error. If it ok you need to clear (set to null) the date of the last request for a new password.

Comment: nice information sir the actual problem is that how to create a new table as of the sent email we can save the time and put the check for 24 hrs in the node sir ,i'm new to node.js